# Seleccionar primera pantalla con api google

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api

Buen día
Un cliente me ha solicitado que ha la captura de la pantalla en full screen del navegador , estoy usando la librería RecordRTC.js que tiene integrado el uso de la api de google para compartir pantalla, pero lo que quiere el cliente es que por defecto seleccione la primer pantalla y no aparezca el cuadro de dialogo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como comento quiero que inmediatamente capture la pantalla 1 es decir en este caso que esta integrada a la computadora

Vi en Internet que se puede hacer uso del atributo deviceId pero como se obtiene o se integra lo tengo de esta manera

```
function invokeGetDisplayMedia(success, error) {
  
   if(navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia) {
    var displaymediastreamconstraints = {
        video: {
          "aspectRatio": 1.7777777777777777,
          "deviceId": "screen:0:0",
          "frameRate": 30,
          "height": 1080,
          "resizeMode": "crop-and-scale",
          "width": 1920,
            displaySurface: 'monitor', 
            logicalSurface: true,
            "frameRate": 30,
            cursor: 'always',
        }
    };

    displaymediastreamconstraints = {
        "aspectRatio": 1.7777777777777777,
      "deviceId": "screen:0:0",
      "frameRate": 30,
      "height": 1080,
      "resizeMode": "crop-and-scale",
      "width": 1920,
      "cursor": "always",
      "displaySurface": "monitor",
      "logicalSurface": true,
        video: true,
    };

    
        navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displaymediastreamconstraints).then(success).catch(error);
    }
    else {
        navigator.getDisplayMedia(displaymediastreamconstraints).then(success).catch(error);
    }
}
```

Gracias y buen día :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día ya se me respondió mejor en la versión de ingles de esta pagina , y la respuesta es que no se puede ya que la ventana esta solicitando al usuario permiso de compartir la venta, para mas detalles dejo el link donde se me pudo responder esta duda:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63564370/select-first-monitor-api-google